# Jar null point exception when reading a file

Tags: java, file, jar

The following code works fine on my Eclipse IDE.

```
private void getLayersAndDisplay() throws Exception {
        URL imageURL = ImageLab.class.getResource("earthlights.jpg");
        File imageFile = new File(imageURL.toURI());
        URL shapeFileURL = ImageLab.class.getResource("countries.shp");
        File shapeFile = new File(shapeFileURL.toURI());
        URL shapeFileURL2 = ImageLab.class.getResource("Brasil.shp");
        File shapeFile2 = new File(shapeFileURL2.toURI());
        displayLayers(imageFile, shapeFile,shapeFile2);
    }
```

However, when compiling to a jar, it gives me a null pointer exception. I thought that since I am getting it as a class.getResource, it would work. Can't I use the File class in a jar? Not even in a cast?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entry of a zip file (that's what a jar file is) is not a file existing in your file system. So you can't use a File, which represents a path on your filesystem, to refer to a zip entry. And you can't use file IO to read its content, since it's not a file.

I have no idea what you want to do, but if you want to read the content of the jar resource, just use `ImageLab.class.getResourceAsStream()` to get an InputStream back, reading from the entry.

Comment: The problem is, that I need a File type and not a Stream type for a method from an API to work.

Comment: Then fix that API, if possible, or read from your zip entry and write to a temporary file, then pass this temporary file so that the broken API can read it again.